# Discretising a PDE using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pde

I want to solve the following PDE which describes the time evolution of a membrane

[image]

The PDE is discretised as follows

[image: ![enter image description here]

where

[image]

and `x(s_i) = x_i`, `j=0,1`, and `x^j=x`, `x^j=y`. We are ignoring the pressure term for now as well as constants like `k_t` etc.

We wish to find `x(t)` using a forward Euler method, by setting `x = x + h*dx/dt`, with `h=1e-6`.

My solution (for `x(t)`) is as follows (ignoring the `y` terms for ease of answering)

```
l = [359,1:358]; 
r = [2:359,1]; %left and right indexing vectors

l1 = [358,359,1:357]; %twice left neighbour
r1 = [3:359,1,2]; %twice right neighbour
 
%create initial closed contour with coordinates x and y
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,360); phi(end) = []; %since closed curve

x = (5 + 0.5*sin(20*phi)).*cos(phi);
y = (5+0.5*sin(20*phi).*cos(phi);
 
ds2 = (1/360)^2;
 
for i = 1:2e5
lengths = sqrt( (x-x(r)).^2 + (y-y(r)).^2 );

Tx=(1/10)/ds2*(x(r) -2*x +x(l) - x0*(((x(r)-x)/lengths)-((x-x(l))/lengths(l))     )  );

%tension term

Bx = 1/ds2^2*(x(r1) - 2*x(r) + x -2(x(r) -2*x + x(l)) + x -2*x(l) + x(l1) ); %bending term

x = x + 1/(1e6)*(Tx); % - Bx); 
% Euler forward step

end
```

Currently, the code runs, but in the last line, if I decomment out the Bx term, the program fails to run. It seems as though my Bx matches what's in the discretisation, but obviously not.

[image]

Comment: Why is your iterating variable `j` not in the loop?  That aside, try to isolate the problems by examining your own code step after step --- you are welcome to ask others; I for one will be reluctant to review a large passage of script with unnecessary components for the question. Use [minimal, generic exampls](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And be more precise in describing what went wrong. What is the expected behavior? What are the error messages you received from Matlab? etc etc

Comment: I have explained what `j` is in the pde and have stripped down the code to bare minimum. I have also added in what I expect and what the errors are.

Comment: The edits look good. Now I understand your general intention. So I am asking about your code in particular: in the for loop starting with `for j=1:2e5`, how are `Bx`, `By` changing at all? `Bx`, `By` look like they are re-defined to the same quantities 2e5-1 times. When you say you want to express a term of a PDE, do you mean you are going to solve the overall PDE? I see the term expressed but without an overall solution, why should blue go to orange in your graph?

Comment: I've added the full eq for the PDE I'm trying to solve, though my solution only contains the evolution of `x` terms for simplicity. I started the program with just the elastic force term `Ex`, (or if I comment out `Bx` from the current solution) and the code works fine. But when I add in the bending term, it fails to run and explodes. So the problem seems to be with `Bx`, though I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: I think you are much better off providing both the PDE (possibly original + discretizd) and your formula for the time evolution of x. One cannot run your code. So I would make it executable. In your code, I don't understand your intention with `x` and `y`. You are using them both as single values *and* as functions. Indeed, I am being very reluctant towards reading anything other than a minimal example, which simplification should help.  But simplification does not cutting out the description of your problem. In the interest of getting an answer, I would not do that.

Comment: Simplifying means: can you reduce your specific problem (ie. the PDE equation and thus your code) down to something more generic? For example, just first term in the sum, or just the second term, etc. If you end up communicating the same issue, then definitely do it. From my perspective, if it seems like the question can be asked with a simpler generic example, I start to wonder why isn't it. If you feel you can't ask the question with a simpler example, feel free to say so. That's fine. Explanation in the question is better than no explanation in the question.

Comment: I see dx/dt on the left. And discretized version on the right. Do you mean x(t) instead? If so, I can share with you what I would do if I were you.

Comment: I've added in more context as to what I'm doing as well as both forms of the PDE. I've also simplified `Bx` to just one term (as even this causes an error), but kept in `Tx` to illustrate the problem. My apologies for writing such a poor question in the first place.

Comment: No worries. And just so you know, the question appears completely different now! In terms of debugging, is the code snippet actual Matlab code of pseudo code? You didn't define `x` as a function but you use `x(r)`. Is that accounted for in your own runs?

Comment: As for the use of forward euler, are you certain? In your current pde, you label the time derivative as partial. That usually means x is a function something and time while that something is also a function of time. But the discretized version labels x as total derivative? If you have an ODE, ODE questions are frequently asked on SO. We typically think of ODE as having some defined go-to methods. And some answers can probably explain how. If you have a numerical method that you wish to implement on Matlab, some answers can probably explain how.

Comment: But if it's not an ODE and if your discretization is what creates the problem, then SO is perhaps not the right platform.

Comment: `x(r)` functions as the `x(s_i+1)` term as it rearranges the array to give the right neighbor of each node. Similarly for `x(l)`. The discretisation is from a PhD thesis (not mine) so it is correct. I think the problem is how I coded the `Bx` term which starts at `k_b` in the ODE. Everything else is the `Tx` term, and using `dx/dt = Tx` works fine in the Euler step. The issue comes when I set `dx/dt = Tx + Bx`.

Comment: I understand x as in the formula. I am talking `x` as in your code. In your code, `x` is not a function. If you run the snippet yourself, it doesn't run. This is also an issue I tried pointing you to: when it comes to debugging, real code >>>>> pseudo.

Comment: Sorry, for the radio silence. My laptop broke and I just got it fixed. I've reworked the code so that it works. Also, I've changed what's in the question to be more clear. Can you let me know why you think the Bx term causes everything to blow up even though it seems to match the discretisation?